# How to convert a plain text .db file to .xlsx and vice versa?

Tags: database, xlsx, converters

I have to convert a `.db` file in plain text to `.xlsx`, and then vice versa.

The problem is the structure of the .db that it's the following:

> {"type":"xxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxx","type2":"xxxxxxx","registry":"X","numproc":"X","aaproc":"xxx","note":"","file":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","date":"xxxxxxxxxxx","date2":"","date3":""},{"type":"xxxxx","id":"xxxxxxxx","type2":"xxxxxxx","registry":"X","numproc":"X","aaproc":"xxx","note":"","file":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","date":"xxxxxxxxxxx","date2":"","date3":""}

and so on.
Every entry is within `{ }` and has several `"field":"content"` separated with a comma. Also, the entries are separated with a comma.
In `xlsx` the "field" should be the label of the column to be filled with the "content". Each entry on a different row.
How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This page is all about _helping_ as opposed to _doing it for_ somebody. So you need to try it yourself in the programming language of your choice and when you get stuck, come back and share the relevant code you have so far and we probably can help you.

Comment: The format of your .DB-file is JSON. You need a JSON to XLSX convert. Try this https://www.aconvert.com/document/json-to-xlsx/ or https://www.coolutils.com/de/online/JSON-to-XLSX.